# Error en laravel 779

Tags: laravel-5

Estaba modificando un par de div y cometí fallos en la sintaxis y me marco el siguiente error desde entonce aunque volví al estado anterior lo que estaba modificando el error continua a que se puede deber ??

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Kernel does
>   not exist in
>   /home/wikidep4/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:779
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/wikidep4/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(779):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('App\Http\Kernel') #1
>   /home/wikidep4/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(658):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\Http\Kernel') #2
>   /home/wikidep4/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(609):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\Http\Kernel', Array) #3
>   /home/wikidep4/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(759):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\Http\Kernel', Array) #4
>   /home/wikidep4/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(264):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\Http\Kernel', Array) #5
>   /home/wikidep4/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Il in
>   /home/wikidep4/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
>   on line 779

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918982/laravel-error-reflectionexception-class-app-http-kernel-does-not-exist

Comment: gracias lo comprobé pero no es mi caso

Comment: Probaste correr `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Fue un error con la carpeta Http se renombro por error cambiando a Htt, solo tuve que volver a renombrarla con el nombre correcto